# How to populate Span elements in an Ajax success setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After a form is submitted (form not shown) My page is receiving a JSON encoded array from my php script with no issue. The page has the following elements that I am trying to populate with the data from json. I'm trying to get the data to show up between the span elements.

```
          <div class="added_display">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>Title: <a href="#link_for_flyer" target="_blank"><span class="title"></span></a></p>
          </li>
          <li style="color: #FF0004">
            <p><span class="comment" style="color: #FF4245"></span></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Address: <span class="address"></span></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Sale Price: <span class="sale-price"></span></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Lease Price: <span class="lease-price"></span></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Lot Size: <span class="lot-size"></span></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Building Size: <span class="building-size"></span></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Zoning: <span class="zoning"></span></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

and the following ajax script directing everything. I am using the span elements class in the success setting:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
$(".data-form").submit(function() {
    data = $(this).serialize();
    if (confirm("Are you ready to sumbmit this listing?\nYou can always edit the listing after going to the menu tab - edit listing."))       
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "add-list.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                      if (response.success) {
                       $("#modal1").modal('hide');
                        $(".added_display").show();
                        $(".title").data(title);
                        $(".comment").data(comment);
                        $(".address").data(address);
                        $(".sale-price").data(sale_price);
                        $(".lease-price").data(lease_price);
                        $(".lot-size").data(lot_size);
                        $(".building-size").data(build_size);
                        $(".zoning").data(zoning);
                        $(".ad_link").data(ad_link);
                        }
                      else {
                          console.log("An error has ocurred: sentence: " + response.sentence + "error: " + response.error);
                      }
                  },
                  error: function() {
                      alert("An Error has ocurred contacting the server. Please contact your system administrator");
                  }
              });
        return false;
      }
   }); 
 });
```

I think my error is tied up in the success setting. How can I correct this code to populate my span elements?

Comment: the variables you have such as comment, address etc, where are these being initialized? should they not be coming from the response object? also what is the reason for using the jquery .data() method instead of say text();?

Comment: there is an html form on the same page that is setting these values which are all text field data, Except the ad_link variable, which is a URL to a file that gets uploaded on that form as well. I'm wondering if the file is causing the problem here as well. As for why the data() method. That is part of my question here, how to format the success function to correctly pull the json data

Comment: also see the line $(".title").html(); i edit's to represent what I am currently working with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.data(value);` try `.text(value);`

The as per [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/), .data() will store arbitrary data on an element. It won't be used to display a value in the DOM. If you want to set the text inside an element use [.text(text)](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text).

If the values are HTML, use [.html(htmlString)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString).

Comment: and the data method should it also be text?

Comment: i'm getting [object HTMLTextAreaElement] printed in between the span elements

Comment: In that case you're looking for the .html method, see my edited answer.